# Nginx not compressing tff files

Tags: nginx

I have added this to my nginx config

```
gzip_types application/javascript application/font-ttf text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;
```

But when I run a [webpagetest.org](http://webpagetest.org) I get this result

```
Use gzip compression for transferring compressable responses: 67/100

707.7 KB total in compressible text, target size = 471.6 KB - potential savings = 236.1 KB

WARNING - (167.7 KB, compressed = 88.1 KB - savings of 79.5 KB) - https://example.com/static/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
WARNING - (166.4 KB, compressed = 88.0 KB - savings of 78.5 KB) - https://example.com/static/fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf
WARNING - (166.8 KB, compressed = 88.7 KB - savings of 78.1 KB) - https://example.com/static/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf
```

Should I add in a different type of `gzip_types` to the config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default nginx configuration shipped with nginx doesn't include a MIME type for TrueType font files. You can see the MIME types that are configured in the shipped file `/etc/nginx/mime.types`.

You can add to the existing [`types`](https://nginx.org/r/types) block in your nginx configuration.

```
types {

    .....

    application/x-font-ttf ttf;
}
```

Though you should probably use the official MIME type `font/ttf` rather than the interim MIME type that you had tried to use.